# How to animate Google Maps API KML Ground Overlay

Tags: api, animation, maps, overlay, kml

Two questions:

1. What is the best way to create a smooth animation through 12 KML Files through google maps API V2?
2. How can I integrate a fadeIn() / fadeOut() to smoothly transtition between these KML files?

I have experimented some with setTimeouts() with 2 of my KML filed but haven't figured out a smooth or consistent way to animate between them. Code is below.

```
function animate () {

function series_1 () {
   geoXml = new GGeoXml("lake/colors_test.kml");
   map.addOverlay(geoXml);
   setTimeout("map.removeOverlay(geoXml)", 5000);

}

function series_2 () {
    geoXml1 = new GGeoXml("lake/colors_test_1.kml");
    map.addOverlay(geoXml1);
    setTimeout("map.removeOverlay(geoXml1)", 5000);

}

series_1();
series_2();


}


animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to apply fading to the underlying images:

```
$("#mapContent").find("img[src*=\"lyrs=kml\"]").fadeOut();
```

This is for the V3 API, you might need a different selector for the V2 API.

I'm assuming the map is created with

```
map = new google.maps.Map document.getElementById("mapContent");
```

jQuery also has a `fadeIn()` method, however it gets tricky because the images are probably recreated when you add a new KML layer. You'll need to find a way to set their visibility to zero when they are created.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to figure out how to translate to google maps v2. I tried this with no luck:         map.find("img[src*=\"lyrs=kml\"]").fadeOut();

Comment: Have you made any animations between KML files like this? Do I need to make my own custom animation with timeouts or is their an animation framework that would work?

Comment: I was assuming you're using jQuery because you mentioned `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. `find` is a jQuery method, not Google Maps.

Comment: I am trying to use jquery - thanks for the .find() tip. To make this work in v2 do I need to change this part of your code? $("#mapContent")

Comment: Also anyway to fadein() the kml / image?

Comment: I'm assuming the map is created with `map = new google.maps.Map document.getElementById("mapContent")`. jQuery also has a fadeIn() method, however it gets tricky because the images are probably recreated when you add a new KML layer. You'll need to find a way to set their visibility to zero when they are created.

Comment: my map id is #map, however, $("#map").find("img[src*=\"lyrs=kml\"]").fadeOut(); does not work in my map - Could this be an issue of V2?

Comment: Yes, v2 might have different URLs for the images, or do something different. I don't think I can help further, my experience is with v3. You can easily investigate this with Chrome developer tools or Firebug.